# Configure Nginx for socket connect

Tags: python, nginx, flask, websocket

I'm working on a Flask app where I need to have a socket connection to all files in a specific directory. Right now I'm using a Python3 http.server (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) which does what I need, but it's not recommended for production. Is there a way to configure Nginx to function in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring your server block include this.

```
`location /{
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass      unix:///path/to/your/socket.sock;
    }
```

It will automatically create a socket file when you run the uwsgi server.

The functioning of uwsgi is beyond the scope of this question if you want to check it out look at:
[detailed uwsgi guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/uwsgi/)